# Why don't Kubernetes deployments support services?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to K8s, so still trying to get my head around things. I've been looking at [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and can appreciate how useful they will be. However, I don't understand why they don't support services (only replica sets and pods).

Why is this? Does this mean that services would typically be deployed outside of a deployment?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Kubernetes deployments are used for managing stateless services running in the cluster instead of [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) which are built for the stateful application run-time. Actually, with deployments you can describe the update strategy and road map for all underlying objects that have to be created during implementation.Therefore, we can distinguish separate specification fields for some objects determination, like needful replica number of Pods, template for Pod by describing a list of containers that should be in the Pod, etc.

However, as @P Ekambaram already mention in his answer, [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) represent abstraction layer of network communication model inside Kubernetes cluster, and they declare a way to access Pods within a cluster via corresponded [Endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#endpoints-v1-core). Services are separated from deployment object manifest specification, because of their mission to dynamically provide specific network behavior for the nested Pods without affecting or restarting them in case of any communication modification via appropriate Service [Types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, services should be deployed as separate objects. Note that deployment is used to upgrade or rollback the image and works above ReplicaSet

Kubernetes Pods are mortal. They are born and when they die, they are not resurrected. ReplicaSets in particular create and destroy Pods dynamically (e.g. when scaling out or in). While each Pod gets its own IP address, even those IP addresses cannot be relied upon to be stable over time. This leads to a problem: if some set of Pods (let’s call them backends) provides functionality to other Pods (let’s call them frontends) inside the Kubernetes cluster, how do those frontends find out and keep track of which backends are in that set?

Services.come to the rescue. 
A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them.  The set of Pods targeted by a Service is (usually) determined by a Label Selector

Comment: I understand the purpose of services. What I don't understand is why they can't be described in a deployment object as well as pods/replica sets.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've just learnt that is somewhat related to my question: multiple K8s objects can be included in the same yaml file, separate by `---`. Something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
# other stuff here
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
# other stuff here
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it intends to decoupled and fine-grained.